# How to use Ellipsis in react-bootstrap pagination

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-bootstrap

Hi i am using react pagination and its working fine and using pagination with apis. but not getting in proper way. when i am using **{paginationItems}** then its show all pages in one line and i want to use this in Ellipsis

**This result i am getting**
[image]

**This result i want**
[image]

**My code**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import Pagination from "react-bootstrap/Pagination";

    const PaginationComponent = ({
      total = 0,
      itemsPerPage = 10,
      currentPage = 1,
      onPageChange,
    }) => {
      const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(0);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (total > 0 && itemsPerPage > 0)
          setTotalPages(Math.ceil(total / itemsPerPage));
      }, [total, itemsPerPage]);
    
      const paginationItems = useMemo(() => {
        const pages: any = [];
    
        for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
          pages.push(
            <Pagination.Item
              key={i}
              active={i === currentPage}
              onClick={() => onPageChange(i)}
            >
              {i}
            </Pagination.Item>
          );
        }
    
        return pages;
      }, [totalPages, currentPage]);
    
      if (totalPages === 0) return null;
    
      return (
        <Pagination className="paginationInfo">  
          <Pagination.Prev
            onClick={() => onPageChange(currentPage - 1)}
            disabled={currentPage === 1}
          />
          {paginationItems}
          <Pagination.Next
            onClick={() => onPageChange(currentPage + 1)}
            disabled={currentPage === totalPages}
          />
        </Pagination>
      );
    };
    
    export default PaginationComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your logic that loops and adds pagination items to use a helper function to create the pagination items:

```
const createPaginationItem = (i) => {
    return <Pagination.Item
        key={i}
        active={i === currentPage}
        onClick={() => onPageChange(i)}
      >
        {i}
      </Pagination.Item>
};
```

To get the layout you want where you have 2 lots of ellipsis:

```
<< | < | 1 |...| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |...| 20 | > | >>
```

you can change your loop as follows:

```
const paginationItems = [];
// Add the first item (page 1)
paginationItems.push(createPaginationItem(1));
// Add the first ellipsis
paginationItems.push(<Pagination.Ellipsis />);
// Create page numbers in the middle (10-14)
const midpoint = totalPages/2;
for (let i = midpoint; i <= midpoint + 4; i++) {
  paginationItems.push(createPaginationItem(i));
}
// Add the second ellipsis
paginationItems.push(<Pagination.Ellipsis />);
// Add the last item (page 20)
paginationItems.push(createPaginationItem(totalPages));
```

See [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bootstrap-examples-bdo75r?file=index.js) for a working demo.

Comment: #lan A, Your demo does't work and is always showing "onPageChange is not defined" error when you click on item

Comment: The demo was really just to show how the pagination controls would look using the ellipsis. I've modified the demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bootstrap-examples-xtkack?file=index.js) which will update the page when pressing the buttons (but the page numbers between the sets of ellipsis remain the same)

Comment: @IanA think the ask was to create a dynamic row of paginated items. In your demo, the user won't be able to see the page number if it lies somewhere in between the start and mid-range. e.g. page no. 2 won't be visible

Comment: @ssindher11 I've created a StackBlitz [here](stackblitz.com/edit/react-bootstrap-examples-su2vth?file=index.js) that takes into account the current page number and dynamically creates the pages. You can edit the current page on line 11 of the link above to see how it behaves